# is gnuplot fit influenced by terminal?

Tags: gnuplot

i have a gnuplot script file to fit measurement data, using this structure:

```
set terminal png

...some format templates...

f(x) = a + b*x + c*x**2

fit f(x) "datafile.txt" using "X":"Y" via a, b, c

...some plotting commands etc...
```

with this, gnuplot shows some strange behaviour:

- when i run the script as-is, it gives me the following error:

  ```
  Undefined value during function evaluation
  "myscriptfile.gnuplot", line 5: error during fit
  ```
- when i move the `set terminal png` line after the `fit` line, it runs without a hassle.
- normally, i'm loading this at the beginning of a master script containing format templates and further data processing routines. doing this also gives me the aforementioned error message, even with the moved `set terminal` command.

since this is just the first part of processing my data i really need it to work from the master script... i already tried setting initial guesses, FIT_LIMIT and loading it from a gnuplot environment. i'm using gnuplot 4.6.5.

does anyone know how to solve this or how `fit` gets influenced by other commands? or is this some kind of bug?

**edit:** uploaded a stripped down version of scripts and data files to [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByjOpEOYcTVLZjBndm10cXdUbVk/edit?usp=sharing). with the reduced data files the computed fits don't concur with the measured points, but with the complete data they do.

Comment: You are right, fitting shouldn't depend on the terminal. However its impossible to check whats going on without having a *complete* example for testing. So please make *minimal* example which shows your problem (only a few lines of your data file, and only the essential script parts).

Comment: i uploaded a (not) working example, see edit at the bottom.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That looks quite strange. First I could reproduce this, later not... I'll have a second look later this evening to see whats going on.

Comment: thanks. btw, if i omit the "load file" part and paste the contents directly into the master file, it works... more and more this sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, what the real error is, but it seems to be related to your use of `using "PHEAT":"RHOT"`, although that should be fine.

I could reproduce your error with the following minimal setup:

A data file `test.dat`:

```
A B
1 2
2 3 
3 4
```

and a file `test.gp`:

```
f(x) = a*x**2 + b*x + c
fit f(x) 'test.dat' using "A":"B" via a,b,c
```

If I call this file with `gnuplot test.gp` I get the same error as you. It doesn't appear if I use `using 1:2`. If I paste the code in an interactive terminal, the error also appears, but only once. If I repeat only the `fit` command again, it works fine. I'll report this as a bug.

In the script you posted, I was also able to fix this by using `using 9:8` instead of `using "PHEAT":"RHOT"`. Additionally you must remove the first line of the data file, which can be done on-the-fly with `tail`, so that you can leave the `using` statements of the `plot` unchanged. So you can use:

```
fit rhotside(x) "< tail -n +2 testdata.txt" using 9:8 via rhot0, rhot1, rhot2
fit rcoldside(x) "< tail -n +2 testdata2.txt" using 9:8 via rcold0, rcold1, rcold2
```

Comment: I always get the error for `using "A":"B"`, also if I repeat it.

Comment: @Bernhard I filed a bug, [#1467 Fit using named columns not working](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1467/). Seems like this is not exactly reproducable on different computers, but in some way it always gives problems. We'll see, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: thanks a lot, i could make it work this way. let's see if the bug can be fixed until the 5.0 release.